# Getting error 505 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Tags: .htaccess, web

my .htaccess file i below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,QSA,L]4
```

is it .htaccess error

Comment: This may help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error

Comment: 505 = "HTTP Version Not Supported". It sounds unlikely unless you're using an *extremely* old server. Are you sure it isn't a 500 error? (that would be more plausible)

Comment: Just to confirm, your rewrite rule is fine. Test it [here](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) to confirm. There must be something else wrong, but honestly, it could be anything. Check your server logs; the actual error should be reported there.

Comment: ya i think it's my web server error

Comment: delete the "4" after the `[NC,QSA,L]`